# How to lookup multiple entries in table to calculate proportion?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a table of lots of sports teams. For each team I need to know the number of fans attending their game as a percentage of all the fans in that region with the same name suffix. The table below gives you an idea of what I'm working with:

```
Region      Team                    Suffix   Attending Fans
North West  blue city               city    181
North East  Black and white united  united  130
North West  blue and white city     city    101
North East  Purple United           united  12
North East  red city                city    73
North East  red and white                   112
North West  Red city                city    162
North East  white shorts united     united  93
North East  orange and black city   city    68
North West  pink united             united  4
North West  red united              united  192
North West  orange united           united  42
```

In the above example, the percentage of attending Red City fans as a proportion of the attending fans from all North West teams suffixed with 'city' is 36.48 %.

What I would like to know is

1. How to lookup the relevant elements so that I can perform the calculation?
2. How to automate this so it occurs for every team (including those that do not have a suffix)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way. The idea is to perform a `groupby.sum()` and map this onto the dataframe as part of your calculation.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['North West', 'blue city', 'city', 181],
                   ['North East', 'Black and white united', 'united', 130],
                   ['North West', 'blue and white city', 'city', 101],
                   ['North East', 'Purple United', 'united', 12],
                   ['North East', 'red city', 'city', 73],
                   ['North East', 'red and white', '', 112],
                   ['North West', 'Red city', 'city', 162],
                   ['North East', 'white shorts united', 'united', 93],
                   ['North East', 'orange and black city', 'city', 68],
                   ['North West', 'pink united', 'united', 4],
                   ['North West', 'red united', 'united', 192],
                   ['North West', 'orange united', 'united', 42]],
                  columns=['Region', 'Team', 'Suffix', 'Attending Fans'])

g = df.groupby(['Region', 'Suffix'])['Attending Fans'].sum()

df['Pct'] = 100 * df['Attending Fans'] / np.fromiter(map(g.get,
            map(tuple, df[['Region', 'Suffix']].values)), dtype=float)

#         Region                    Team  Suffix  Attending Fans         Pct
# 0   North West               blue city    city             181   40.765766
# 1   North East  Black and white united  united             130   55.319149
# 2   North West     blue and white city    city             101   22.747748
# 3   North East           Purple United  united              12    5.106383
# 4   North East                red city    city              73   51.773050
# 5   North East           red and white                     112  100.000000
# 6   North West                Red city    city             162   36.486486
# 7   North East     white shorts united  united              93   39.574468
# 8   North East   orange and black city    city              68   48.226950
# 9   North West             pink united  united               4    1.680672
# 10  North West              red united  united             192   80.672269
# 11  North West           orange united  united              42   17.647059
```